# Block User using IP Address in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to block or allow user using there IP addresses. So I need a specific IP for each user. Can you tell how can I achieve this? I am using codeigniter framework. I want to get User's Unique IP address.

Comment: Use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: Ip dose not equal user

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  will get my Server's IP, won't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an array of blocked ip address and then check each users ip if that is the blocked ip arrays then block the user else carry own the application. See the psudo code below to get an idea.

```
$blockedIps = array("185.215.188.170","105.215.178.165","119.115.108.100");
$currentUserIp = $this->input->ip_address();

if(in_array($currentUserIp, $blockedIps)){

//block user functionality goes here

}else{

//else resume application

}
```

Comment: How can I get users IP Adress?

Comment: $this->input->ip_address(); will give you current user ip address.

Comment: this is giving me public IP. I think it is giving me my router's IP, is it possible to get user's unique ID, because it is possible that many users connect with same router and If I use this function it will block all users connected to that router.

Comment: If that is the case then you should not block user by ip address, because you can block it by public ip only. It will block all the users who are connected with that ip via same router. If you have user login/registration system then you can block it via username/email or if you are seeking any other alternative then you should use physical address (MAC address) of the user's laptop/pc, but that will block it completely even if he/she is connected with different IP as blockage is not by ip it will be by machine address. Please note that MAC address can't be get by php.

Comment: Is there any way to get user's Mac address?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "111.111.111") === 0))
{
    die();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your code?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$blockIP = array("192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2");
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $blockIP))
{
 echo "BLOCK";
 exit();
}
else
{
   echo "ALLOW";
}
?>
```